# generateSW skips node_modules directory

Tags: workbox

I am using workbox 4.1.0.

My workbox-config.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  "globDirectory": "web/",
  "globPatterns": [
    "**/*.{html,js,gawk,png,gif,jpg,jpeg,txt,css,ts}"
  ],
  "swDest": "web/sw.js",
};
```

I create web/sw.js with the following command:

```
workbox generateSW workbox-config.js
```

I have a directory under *web* named *node_modules*.  In it, I have a number of *.js files.  For some reason, the *sw.js* file generated by *generateSW* is skipping all the files under *web/node_modules*.  How can I make it include those too?

Thanks.

Blake McBride

Answer (score 0):

It looks like workbox ignores `node_modules` by default. You can clear out `globIgnores` and then they will be included.

```js
  globPatterns: [
    'node_modules/**/*',
  ],
  globIgnores: [],
```

Comment: Yea, thanks.  This "feature" seems somewhat arbitrary to me but it's easy enough to fix.  Thanks.

Comment: A `node_modules` directory could easily contains 100s of MB of code so I'm not surprised it's excluded by default.